# Domain accounts failing to work after two days

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to diagnose/troubleshoot an issue where users to a Sharepoint site are not able to login anymore after 2 days from an initial password change (these are domain accounts). The password gets changed by IT Support, and then after two days, they are not able to login.

There is one (I know, bad, but I didn't decide this) DC with SQL Server, and a MOSS server. I have looked at the event logs, turned on auditing, got the netlogon log (kerberos logging) enabled, used netpwage to get password ages, but have not found any reason for this?

I know that after the max password age the user cannot login anymore, so I used that cmd tool (netpwage) and saw some accounts (not every account is listed for some reason) approaching 30 days pw age, but no clue as to why the account would fail to work after 2 days?

If anymore information is required, please ask!

Comment: What event is recorded in the security log for the login failures?

Comment: Erik, sorry! @Shane, 4776 with either password incorrect or (rarely) username does nto exist. Password incorrect more likely. User does not exist was one case.

Comment: To clarify: Are these new or existing users? You said initial password change: So the user is logging in, changing their password and then it no longer works with the new password? Are the accounts showing as disabled in AD? Is it possible the users are logging into Sharepoint, saving their IT assigned password and trying to login, and after too many attempts they're locked out?